# Logging in on Steam - CasperJS

Tags: javascript, authentication, casperjs, steam

I want to login on Steam with CasperJS, but it just dont want to work.

This is my code:

```
var url = 'https://steamcommunity.com/login/';

casper.start(url, function() {
    console.log("page loaded");


casper.waitForSelector("form input[name='username']", function() {
}, true);   
    this.fill('form[name="logon"]', { 
        username: 'username', 
        password:  'password'
    }, true);
    this.click('form input#SteamLogin');
});
```

After executing this code, CasperJS said:

```
[info] [remote] submitting form to #, HTTP POST
[warning] [remote] unable to submit form
```

I also used the function "StartLogin" (i found the function in the sourcecode of steam) and executed it with this:

```
casper.evaluate(function(){
    StartLogin();
});
```

But CasperJS came up with this error:

```
Page Error: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: StartLogin
```

Would be very thankful, if someone could help me :)

Comment: Which PhantomJS version do you use? Please register to the `resource.error`, `page.error`, `remote.message` and `casper.page.onResourceTimeout` events ([Example](https://gist.github.com/artjomb/4cf43d16ce50d8674fdf#file-2_caspererrors-js)). Maybe there are errors.

Comment: PhantomJS is 1.9.7 and CasperJS is 1.1.0-beta3. These error events don't print anything, so I don't think that there is an error. The reason why it cant find StartLogin is, that the function is really missing in the casperJS source. But if I look into the source with my browser, I can see this function.

Comment: Your `waitForSelector()` call isn't doing anything, because it's empty and everything after it is executed before it. Move the fill and click into that function.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is quite vague, but I am trying to help

You have to know the difference between the `casper.evaluate` and the classic `assert` statement, I think you mixed something up there

`casper.evaluate` evaluates a specific statement in the context of phatom, it doesnt evaluate any functions.
If you want to evaluate the proper `return` of a function use it like this:

```
var val = casper.evaluate(function() {if(true) return 'foo';});
test.assertEquals(val,'foo');
```

I hope I could help you a little bit, for further infos look at:

1. [CasperJS evaluate](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#evaluate)
2. [Tester module casper](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/tester.html)
3. [CasperJS Plugin for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/resurrectio/kicncbplfjgjlliddogifpohdhkbjogm)

Answer (score 0):

In the fill function you are setting the submit bool to true so the form is being submitted after the username and password are filled out.

Take out the `this.click`, then add `casper.then(function(){})` to the end to execute your next command.

Basically you are trying to click a button that is not there because you have already moved on to the next page by submitting your form.

Hope this helps!